# High res images on low pixel density screens

Tags: android, android-drawable

Regarding [Android's call to provide multiple versions of a bitmap/image](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp), why can't *only* the highest resolution image be used?

[image]

E.g if the xxhdpi image is available - will that be able to scale down to all lower density versions or will it just mean it will scale bigger than the allocated size (`View`)?

PS: If I'm using a background image, does scaling matter? E.g. should I still provide multiple versions of 1 image to fit different pixel densities?

Answer (score 0):

Usually image scaling operation is resourceful and the outcome might be worse than using pre-scaled image.

Answer (score 0):

It has already been answered several times, but I will answer it again. Btw I'm not myself a big pro in Android, but I will try to answer in the best way possible.

Automatic scaling is a thing in Android, but using that is a waste of resource, we already know that using a PNG Graphic asset is a waste of CPU/GPU power when we can use XML for basic designs (which uses less resources), so why waste more power for downscaling it (which increases app opening time and makes it laggy), simply creating multiple sized images for different display sizes is the best option.

A simple and convenient option is to use a free software like **Adobe XD** which supports export into different sizes.

**Simple answer:** Avoid using PNG(or other image format), but when you don't have other options do create multiple sizes to save resources.